# SQL on SAS Convert date column format 01/01/2023 into a integer column format 202301

Tags: sql, date, sas

SQL on SAS I need to create a new column and convert the column date_sale in date format lite that 01/01/2023 into a integer column format 202301

My column

date format | integer format

| date_sale | date_i_want |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | 202301 |
| 01/02/2023 | 202302 |

this is my code:

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE work.sales AS 
   SELECT t1.quantity, 
          t1.value, 
          t1.date_sale, 
          t1.segmento,
      t1.date_canceling
          
      FROM wws.table_sale t1
      
QUIT;
```

I don´t know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

A data step will make this easier to work with. Combine the parts of your date together and add leading zeros where necessary. Let's create sample data:

```
data have;
    do date = '01JAN2023'd to '31JAN2023'd;
        output;
    end;

    format date mmddyy10.;
run;
```

Now let's create the value we want:

```
data want;
    set have;
    date_want = input(cats(year(date), put(day(date), z2.)), 8.);
run;
```

Breaking down each piece going inner-to-outer:

`day(date)` - Gets the day part of the date

`put(day(date), z2.)` - Adds leading zeros to the day part of the date

`cats(year(date), put(day(date), z2.))` - Concatenates the year and day part like this: `202301`

`input(cats(year(date), put(day(date), z2.)), 8.)` - Converts the entire string into an integer

You could also do this with SQL if you wanted to.

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE work.sales AS 
   SELECT input(cats(year(t1.date), put(day(t1.date), z2.)), 8.) as date_want, 
          t1.quantity, 
          t1.value, 
          t1.date_sale, 
          t1.segmento,
      t1.date_canceling
          
      FROM wws.table_sale t1
      
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Oldy but still works, can be used in SQL or data step

```
year(t1.date)*100+month(t1.date) as date_i_want
```

Comment: Now that's just mathematically fun